# HTML Element in side menu not scaling to content of parent

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Edit: 
WOW! Long day! I had not saved the fiddle...! Here is the working example. Thanks for any help.

---

I have created a [fiddle here](https://jsfiddle.net/TheRealPapa/ged1dy00/) of my issue.

I am using [this menu](http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/simple_sidebar_menu.html) as the basis for a page I am working on.

The menu uses `Bootstrap 3`, and `jQuery`.

I cannot figure out why the black sidebar (`#sidebar-wrapper`) does not scale with the contents and always starts at a fixed height. I think the starting height is the visible area of this element.

Essentially I want the menu column to scale as follows:

1. min-height = screen-height - 50px (allow this for the header)
   or
2. its height is the height of the main content (`#page-content-wrapper`) which essentially will contain a variable amount of data.

I have found in research that this CSS grows an element to the page height (as minimum):

```
min-height: 100vh;
```

But have not been able to apply the `50px` difference. Did I understand correctly?

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: try this `height:100vh;
min-height:100vh;

`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use calc() for the min height. It removes 50px from the total height of the page

`min-height: calc(100vh - 50px);`

Answer (score 1):

I think based off your fiddle, its a block element so it gets a fixed height. Additionally, it is within a div so it will share its height with other elements inside of it. From the sample you gave, I was able to replicate it. What it does is give the id `#sidebar-wrapper` attribute of `position:absolute` so it wont take in account any elements but itself.

[Replicated example](https://jsfiddle.net/ged1dy00/1/)

Comment: Sorry @Kelv.Gonzales, I had not saved the fiddle. So how to make it stretch and fill to content on the right? I have it filling the vertical view port, but when the content goes beyond one page, and you scroll down,  the sidebar stops at the bottom of the page and an empty column continues down.

Comment: haha I see. Would you be able to do a screenshot or an image of what you mean? I dont get quite what you want to achieve.

Comment: I have sorted it out by using the suggestions from @Ariana Lynn below. Thanks for helping out!

Answer (score 0):

Try to this example i think your issue is solve

```js
$("#menu-toggle").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled");
    });
     $("#menu-toggle-2").click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $("#wrapper").toggleClass("toggled-2");
        $('#menu ul').hide();
    });

     function initMenu() {
      $('#menu ul').hide();
      $('#menu ul').children('.current').parent().show();
      //$('#menu ul:first').show();
      $('#menu li a').click(
        function() {
          var checkElement = $(this).next();
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            return false;
            }
          if((checkElement.is('ul')) && (!checkElement.is(':visible'))) {
            $('#menu ul:visible').slideUp('normal');
            checkElement.slideDown('normal');
            return false;
            }
          }
        );
      }
    $(document).ready(function() {initMenu();});
```

```css
 /* Toggle Styles */

 #wrapper {
    padding-left: 0;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#wrapper.toggled {
    padding-left: 250px;
    overflow: hidden;
}

#sidebar-wrapper {
    z-index: 1000;
    position: absolute; 
    left: 250px;
    width: 0;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: -250px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    background: #000;
    -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}
#wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
    width: 250px;
}

#page-content-wrapper {
    position: absolute;
    padding: 15px;
    width: 100%;  
    overflow-x: hidden; 
}
.xyz{
    min-width: 360px;
}
#wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
    position: relative;
    margin-right: 0px; 
}
.fixed-brand{
    width: auto;
}
/* Sidebar Styles */

.sidebar-nav {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 250px;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    list-style: none;
    margin-top: 2px;
}

.sidebar-nav li {
    text-indent: 15px;
    line-height: 40px;
}

.sidebar-nav li a {
    display: block;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #fff;
    background: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    border-left: red 2px solid;
}

.sidebar-nav li a:active,
.sidebar-nav li a:focus {
    text-decoration: none;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand {
    height: 65px;
    font-size: 18px;
    line-height: 60px;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a {
    color: #999999;
}

.sidebar-nav > .sidebar-brand a:hover {
    color: #fff;
    background: none;
}
.no-margin{
    margin:0;
}

@media(min-width:768px) {
    #wrapper {
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
    .fixed-brand{
        width: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled {
        padding-left: 0;
    }

    #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper {
        width: 50px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #sidebar-wrapper:hover {
        width: 250px;
    }


    #page-content-wrapper {
        padding: 20px;
        position: relative;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
    }

    #wrapper.toggled #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        padding-left: 250px;
    }
    #wrapper.toggled-2 #page-content-wrapper {
        position: relative;
        margin-right: 0;
        margin-left: -200px;
        -webkit-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -moz-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        -o-transition: all 0.5s ease;
        transition: all 0.5s ease;
        width: auto;

    }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/font-awesome-4.3.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://seegatesite.com/bootstrap/js/jquery-1.11.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.2.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <nav class="navbar navbar-default no-margin">
    <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header fixed-brand">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse"  id="menu-toggle">
                      <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><i class="fa fa-rocket fa-4"></i> SEEGATESITE</a>
                </div><!-- navbar-header-->
 
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                                <li class="active" ><button class="navbar-toggle collapse in" data-toggle="collapse" id="menu-toggle-2"> <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-th-large" aria-hidden="true"></span></button></li>
                            </ul>
                </div><!-- bs-example-navbar-collapse-1 -->
    </nav>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="sidebar-wrapper">
            <ul class="sidebar-nav nav-pills nav-stacked" id="menu">
 
                <li class="active">
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-dashboard fa-stack-1x "></i></span> Dashboard</a>
                       <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li><a href="#">link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">link2</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span> Shortcut</a>
                    <ul class="nav-pills nav-stacked" style="list-style-type:none;">
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>link1</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-flag fa-stack-1x "></i></span>link2</a></li>
 
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-cloud-download fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Overview</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"> <span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-cart-plus fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Events</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-youtube-play fa-stack-1x "></i></span>About</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-wrench fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Services</a>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#"><span class="fa-stack fa-lg pull-left"><i class="fa fa-server fa-stack-1x "></i></span>Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /#sidebar-wrapper -->
        <!-- Page Content -->
        <div id="page-content-wrapper">
            <div class="container-fluid xyz">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-12">
                        <h1>Simple Sidebar With Bootstrap 3 by <a href="http://seegatesite.com/create-simple-cool-sidebar-menu-with-bootstrap-3/" >Seegatesite.com</a></h1>
                        <p>This sidebar is adopted from start bootstrap simple sidebar startboostrap.com, which I modified slightly to be more cool. For tutorials and how to create it , you can read from my site here <a href="http://seegatesite.com/create-simple-cool-sidebar-menu-with-bootstrap-3/">create cool simple sidebar menu with boostrap 3</a></p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /#page-content-wrapper -->
    </div>
    <!-- /#wrapper -->
```